# Каждый элемент List<T> умножить на косинус

Tags: c#

Создал список,в который буду загружать свои значения

```
List<double> moduls = new List<double>();
```

Загружаю свои значения из метода

```
 for (int frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
  {
     moduls.Add(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T))); 
}
```

И теперь самое интересное как мне каждый элемент списка умножить на косинус

```
 public static Complex reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T,int frc,int frc1,double shag)///Обратное преобразование Фурье
       {          
           NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
           int t = 1;
    List<double> moduls = new List<double>();
 for (int frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
           {
 moduls.Add(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T)));     
}
return (1 / 2 * Math.PI) * integration.Calculate(w => moduls.ForEach(x1 => x1 * Math.Cos(anguarFrequency * t)),0, T); ----Проблемная строка       
       }
```

Вопрос такой

Как каждый элемент списка умножить и прибавить через ForEach?
Проблема в том что ругается

```
Ошибка  1   В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и ожидания
```

Вот метод Calculate.

```
class TrapezoidalRule : NumericalIntegrationRule
        {
           public double Calculate(Func<double,double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
            {
                double result = 0;
                double step = (max - min) / subintervalsCount;
                for (double i = min; i < max; i += step)
                    result += ((func(i) + func(i + step)) / 2) * step;
                return result;
            }

        }
```

Занести внутрь пределы интегрирования ForEach не получится,так как потом придётся переделывать метод Calculate а он на многом завязан.

А если буду без создания List<> работать,то у меня одни нули.
Через List<> я могу видеть свои значения и ориентироваться при отладки

Как можно решить эту проблему?

И зачем мне это нужно

Это мне нужно чтобы получить результаты,которые позволят мне вывести приблизительно такой график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ForEach` ничего не возвращает, это раз, судя по всему количество требуемых параметров в Calculate и передаваемых различается: требуется 4( func, min, max, subintervalsCount), передается 3(w => moduls.ForEach(x1 => x1 * Math.Cos(anguarFrequency * t)),0, T), то есть  до ошибки из вопроса еще две

Comment: ну и сама ошибка говорит, какие операции разрешений, в данном случае умножение не является ни присваиванием, ни вызовом функции, инкрементом, декрементом, `await` либо созданием нового объекта

Comment: У вас ошибка еще в реализации какой-то формулы. Вы получили список точек, в завимости от частоты. Затем пытаетесь этот список точек, проинтегрировать в завимиости от времени. Даже если введете функцию, которая будет возвращать точку в зависимости от времени, по-моему, будет бредово. Покажите, что Вы пытаетсь еще реализовать.

Comment: @nuts119 я обновил вопрос.
Мне нужно вывести график,руководитель сказал действовать таким образом,который описан выше.
2 недели мучаюсь с графиком.

Comment: @beginner , что на этом графике? Зависимость чего от чего?

Comment: @nuts119 на этом графике изображён приблизительно восстановленный прямоугольный импульс.

С помощью прямого преобразования Фурье тогда преобразовали его,а с помощью обратного нужно вернуть в исходный вариант или можно в таком виде(который указан выше)

учитывая что в прямом преобразовании строилась зависимость от частоты,а при обратном нужно получить уже зависимость от времени

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то вы хотите всё сложно сделать. Надо умножить на косинус — вот и умножайте на косинус.

```
// Обратное преобразование Фурье
public static Complex reverstrans(
    double U, double anguarFrequency, double T, int frc, int frc1, double shag)
{          
    NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
    int t = 1;
    List<double> moduls = new List<double>();
    for (int frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
    {
        moduls.Add(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T)));     
    }

    // умножаем на косинус
    for (int i = 0; i < moduls.Length; i++)
    {
        // поскольку у вас t нигде не меняется, вычисление косинуса можно
        // вообще вынести за цикл
        moduls[i] *= Math.Cos(anguarFrequency * t);
    }

    // на месте вопросительных знаков вам нужна функция из double в double,
    // её у вас там не было, подставляйте её!
    return (1 / 2 * Math.PI) * integration.Calculate(???, 0, T);
}
```